# How can I remove a containing [" "] from a string variable if it exists?

Tags: javascript

I have string variables that can look like this:

```
var a = '["Email cannot be null or empty."]';
var b = 'test string';
```

Is there a way I can check if the variables start and end in '["' ,  ']"' and if so then these be removed so that the variables become:

```
var a = 'Email cannot be null or empty.';
var b = 'test string';
```

What I am looking for is a one line solution if it's possible. I am not sure if I could use some regex or index function. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use a JSON parser.

Comment: @SLaks - I wasn't aware of that but I would be intersted to learn how I could use it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: `assert(JSON.parse(a)[0] === "Email cannot be null or empty.");`

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I figured OP will see that and put a try/catch and deal with it appropriately :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that is a likely scenario, with few deviations:

```
function unformatString(str) {
   try {
      str = JSON.parse(str);
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(str) === '[object Array]') {
         return str[0];
      }
   } catch (err) { }

   return str;
}

var a = unformatString('["Email cannot be null or empty."]');
var b = unformatString('test string');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the above solution is probably the better one, but an alternative solution for text replacement is the [String.replace() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

You could fix your strings with:

```
a = a.replace("[\"", "");
a = a.replace("\"]", "");
```

This would remove the strings `["` and `"]` from anywhere in the string, whether it is in the front, back, or middle of the string. `String.replace()` also supports regular expressions, not just strings, so you could write a quick regex in its place if necessary.

Comment: Can I do that in one line by adding one replace after the other ?

Comment: Yep, you could do it as `a = a.replace("[\"", "").replace("\"]", "");` since `String.replace()` returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a.indexOf('["')==0 && a.indexOf('"]')==a.length-2)
{
  a = a.replace('[\"', '');
  a = a.replace('\"]', '');
}
```

First I am checking If variables start and end in '["' , ']"'

Comment: An easier way of doing this would be to use the first argument of replace as a regex, instead of checking the location in the strings. You could do the same thing as: `a = a.replace('^[\"', '').replace('\"]$','');`

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove `["` at the beginning and `"]` at the end of a string [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SY6EL/1/)

```
var a = '["Email cannot be null or empty."]';
a = a.replace(/^\[\"/,'').replace(/\"\]$/,'');
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = '["Email cannot be null or empty."]';
a.replace(/[\[\"\]]/g, "")
//output "Email cannot be null or empty."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Regular expressions using exec() method.

```
var cleanInput = function(str) {
    var patt = /\["(.*)"]/g;
    if( (result = patt.exec(str)) !== null )
        return result[1];
    else
        return str;
},
    input1 = '["Dummy string"]',
    input2 = '["Another dummy string"]',


    // Checking Inputs

    input1 = cleanInput(input1),
    input2 = cleanInput(input2);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Uu8Ht/**